# Motion of an object that always has an acceleration perpendicular to its velocity

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, vector-analysis, physics

Consider an object whose position vector $x$(changes with time) satisfies the condition
$$
\dot{x}\cdot\ddot{x}=0
$$
i.e. the object is always accelerating in the direction perpendicular to its direction of motion.

How can I solve the DE and find an equation relating $x$ and $t$(the time)? Is it wrong to say that the speed should be constant?

Comment: $\dot{x} \cdot \ddot{x}$ $=g_{ij}\dot{x}^i\ddot{x}^j=\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{1}{2} g_{ij}\dot{x}^i\dot{x}^j)=0$ Then the kinetic energy is constant. So velocity too

Comment: @Baol Oh yes. The force(If we can use this concept) is acting in a perpendicular direction and hence does no work. So KE is constant, unless mass is changing.

Comment: @Baol: the velocity is not constant. The _speed_ is constant.

Comment: A nice example is the standard helix:  $\mathbf{x} = (\cos t, \sin t, t)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simplicity, consider the problem to be two dimensional.

Let $\mathbf v=v_x \mathbf i+v_y \mathbf j$.

So you want to solve
$$\mathbf v\cdot\mathbf {\dot v}=0$$

This is equivalent to solving
$$v_x \dot v_x+v_y \dot v_y=0\qquad{(1)}$$

However, in general, $v_x$ and $v_y$ are independent of each other. With one equation and two unknowns, our problem is underdetermined.

However, it can be mathematically proved that the speed remains constant.

Integrating $(1)$ with respect to $t$ yields
$$v_x^2+v_y^2=C\implies ||\mathbf v||=\text{constant}$$

Comment: That should be $||\mathbf v||=\sqrt C$, I think.

Comment: @TonyK This is correct. But what I want to express is that the magnitude of speed is constant. I’vd edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the speed must be constant. This is just the case of circular motion and yes the speed is constant for a circular motion.